# Creating DirectX device fails in remote desktop

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, rdp

I have an application that uses DirectX to capture the screen. The application works fine locally, however when I run it through a remote desktop session the IDirect3D9::CreateDevice function fails:

```
    d3dpp.Windowed=WINDOW_MODE;
    d3dpp.Flags=D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat=ddm.Format;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight=nDisplayHeight=gScreenRect.bottom =ddm.Height;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth=nDisplayWidth=gScreenRect.right =ddm.Width;
    d3dpp.MultiSampleType=D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect=D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow=hWnd;
    d3dpp.PresentationInterval=D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT;
    d3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz=D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT;

    if(FAILED(g_pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,D3DDEVTYPE_REF,hWnd,D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING ,&d3dpp,&g_pd3dDevice)))
    {
        ErrorMessage("Unable to Create Device");
        return E_FAIL;
    }
```

I am using Windows 7 to access Windows Server 2008 R2 with RDP.

What exactly is wrong here? I read that its possible to do use Direct3D through RDP.

Comment: What graphics driver do you have on your server machine?

Comment: I have installed a normal graphics card, its an NVIDIA.

Comment: I read somewhere that you have to have a WDDM driver.

Comment: Where can I get such a driver, is it hardware specific? Can dxdiag detect if the driver is a WDDM driver?

Comment: I don't know. I don't even know what a WDDM driver really is. It was just something I read when googling around this question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Haha, the problem was I had not the DirectX drivers installed. After it works!

Comment: So the EC2 instance doesn't have Directx installed by default?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the exact reason for failure, but I can give you a direction.
When you connect through the RDP the Windows doesn't load your native video driver at all, and nothing is actually displayed on the monitor. Instead the system loads the RDPDD virtual video driver, which draws everything in the system memory, and sends it to RDP client over the network. This is how remote desktop works.

So that your native video card/driver is not involved at all. RDPDD is a very minimalistic "frame buffer" driver, it does not support Direct3D/DirectDraw at all.

OTOH you call `CreateDevice` with `D3DDEVTYPE_REF` parameter, which should work even if you don't have D3D-compatible video card, the D3D should be emulated in software. Hence - I don't know why this happens. I can guess that the problem may be within the `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` parameters. Perhaps some of them may not be emulated.

Try to check the error code, play with `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` .